# How to do this layout with iframes, in HTML

Tags: html, iframe

[The layout i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4w1h.png)

I dont know how to get the frames to layout in the right position I want, so I could use help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is done using frameset. I have added `frameborder="1"`which will show the border, you can set it to "0" or remove the borders. You can change the border size by adding `border="1px"`. And add `bordercolor:#000;` for adding colors to the border. And for scrolling you can use `scrolling="Yes/No/Auto"` in the `frameset` beggining tag.
The code given below will not work on Stack Overflow, [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen),or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) as `<frameset>` is no longer supported in HTML5. **But you can save the file locally or [try it on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) by pasting the following code, and it will work.**
**Edit the frame sources, else it will not work (as I have given invald pages)**.

```html
<html>
<frameset frameborder="1" rows="20%, 80%"><!--set frameborder value "0" for hiding the borders -->
<frame src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000X150/181818/FFFFFF/?text=20%">
<frameset cols="25%, 75%">
<frame src="https://via.placeholder.com/150X500/181818/FFFFFF/?text=25%">
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
<frame src="https://via.placeholder.com/700X250/181818/FFFFFF/?text=75%">
<frameset cols="75%, 25%">
<frame src="https://via.placeholder.com/600X200/181818/FFFFFF/?text=50%">
<frame src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/181818/FFFFFF/?text=25%">
</frameset>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I never thought, I’d upvote an answer suggesting `<frameset>`, but here I am...

Comment: Glad, you got the answer :-)